# still getting Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT even after setting

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers

My htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
   Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
   <FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|js|css)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=5184000, public"
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"
   # Webfonts
   ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I tried doing `ExpiresActive Off` also i commented each line of this module, event i removed it completely. Also i try `Header set Expires "0"` in `FilesMatch` node. But i am unable to remove the expire. I want expire to show +1 day of the date. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

First check if the .htaccess is read at all. Place some gibberish in the first line, the server should then respond with a 500 error. If there's no error, contact your server's admin, he disabled htaccess processing.

Also note that the htaccess is only valid for the directory it's located in and all its subdirectories.

(BTW, you do not need IfModule statements. When using the htaccess you should know which modules are active. IfModule is directed at third-party software packages and very generic server configuration tasks.)